# Exception caught by scheduler library: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree

Tags: flutter, dart, button, navigation

I am trying to navigate to a page from the Bottom `Navigator` as well as a separate button.

But every time I go back to the home page and click the same button(not the bottom navigator) to go to a particular page again, I get this error:

[image]

Below is the leading app bar icon code.

```
leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => BottomNavBar(index: 3),
              ),
            );
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/menu.svg',
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
```

I am using the same navigator route with multiple buttons on the same page to go to another page.

I have not used Floating Action Button.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: can you share complete source code for the screen and error log

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple buttons in FloatinActionButton, it's not allowed.
Other way is to give unique keys to all the buttons that you have.